# Easy way of obtaining from 1 to MAX(id)+1 in SQL(MS Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to use SQL in MS Access to generate all the numbers from 1 to MAX( id ) + 1. Where id is a column of integers.

I attempted to use the query below but it's not working.

I thought of using a query using auto_increment=1 but I am unsure how this would work

```
Select DadosID 
From PROMIS_LT
Connect By DadosID <= MAX(DadosID) +1
```

Comment: replace DadosID with ID. Sorry I forgot to change that

Comment: no, I want to generate a list of numbers. Number 1 to max(id) +1   . I would need a query to do this